# How to generate predictive values when using Anova (Type III) on mixed effects linear model

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova, mixed-model, predictive-models

I am running a mixed effects linear model on AB test and using Anova, Type III to determine significance. I am doing this because I have an interaction variable.

My R code is :

```
model = lme(DV ~ variation_id + time + variation_id*time, random = ~1|user_id, data=data, method="REML")
sstable <- Anova(model, type = 3)
```

Ordinarily, I would use summary(model) to get coefficients which I use to generate predictive output (DV) but I'm unable to do this with Anova.

What's the best practice for generating predictive estimates when testing significance with Anova?